# How do I use POJO equivalents in Scala?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have the following

```
class SimpleClass (myInt: Int, myString: String) {

}
```

What is wrong with the following?

```
val mySimple = new SimpleClass(1, "hi")
println(mySimple.myInt)
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you want the contructor parameters to be available as fields of the class, you have to declare them as vals or vars:

```
class SimpleClass (val myInt: Int, val myString: String) {

}
```

Comment: Or declare the class as "case class", where you get that sort of thing for free.

Comment: `case class` is closer to POJO; see this for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673233/how-is-the-pojo-javabean-pattern-treated-in-scala

Answer (score 17):

For the full POJO experience™, including equality, hashCodes and sane implementation of `toString`... You'll want case classes:

```
case class SimpleClass(myInt: Int, myString: String)

val mySimple = SimpleClass(1, "hi")
println(mySimple.myInt)
```

Parameters to a case class are automatically made into vals.  You *can* explicitly make them vars if you wish, but this this sort of thing is typically frowned upon in Scala - where immutable objects are favoured.

Answer (score 17):

The java equivalent of your Scala definition is:

```
public class SimpleClass {
   public SimpleClass( int myInt, String myString ) {
   }
}
```

No wonders it doesn't work...

Hey dude, that's your 17th scala question and you are still troubled by the very basics of the language. Perhaps you should take an afternoon and read some of tutorial on-line (or some book) to consolidate your knowledge. I can suggest:

- http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/roundup-scala-for-java-refugees
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-scala02198/index.html (see listings 11-13)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are calling the `SimpleClass.myInt` getter method but you didn't define a getter method anywhere. You need to define the `SimpleClass.myInt` getter method or even better yet, get Scala to automatically define it for you:

```
class SimpleClass(val myInt: Int, myString: String) {}
```