# How is the POJO/JavaBean pattern treated in Scala?

Tags: scala

Just like the question. Does scala promote it same way as Java? Or has it been evolved to be more idiomatic to Scala? Or has it been made irrelevant?

POJOs and JavaBeans meaning:

1. Constructor that takes no parameters
2. attributes are private, getters and setters are public
3. getters and setters defines properties, hiding attributes

---

Also, does Scala have opinions (sorry, I dislike using this term) on using the old `public`, `private`, `protected` attribute designs that is relevant to this question?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Scala also has POJO-like idioms but they are different than JavaBeans and Scala puts emphasis on different aspects.

1. Scala has different naming conventions:

   ```
   def foo: Foo        //Foo getFoo() in Java
   def foo_=(foo: Foo)  //void setFoo(Foo foo) in Java
   ```

   This way you can always write `obj.foo` and `obj.foo = bar` even if you decide to switch from getters/setters to direct field access and vice-versa. This is called *uniform access principle*.
2. Due to Java interoperability, `@BeanProperty` annotation was introduced:

   ```
   @BeanProperty var foo: Foo = _
   ```

   the code above not only creates Scala-like getters/setters, but Java-like as well, so all Java frameworks work seamlessly.
3. Scala forces you to decide between variables (`var`) and values (`val`), so you find yourself much more often using immutable objects
4. I really prefer immutable objects and initialization in constructor, which has been made very easy in Scala:

   ```
   class Foo(val age: Int, val name: String)
   ```

   or even (`val` by default in `case` classes):

   ```
   case class Foo(age: Int, name: String)
   ```

   This piece of code is brilliant in its simplicity. However, if you need to cooperate with Java frameworks, you still need no-argu constructor and setters:

   ```
   public class Foo(var age: Int, var name: String) {

       def this() {
           this(0, "")
       }

   }
   ```

   Note `val` being replaced by `var`.
5. Access modifiers in Scala have slightly better defaults compared to Java:

   ```
   class Foo(var a: Int, x: Int) {

       var b: Int = _

       private var c: Int = _

       private[this] var d: Int = _

       def twisted = a + b + c + d + x

   }
   ```

   Variables `a` and `b` will become `private` fields with `public` getters/setters (fields are private by default, methods are public). `c` and `d` are private variables as well. But the extra `private[this]` makes `d` be accessible directly internally in the class rather than by private getter/setter.

   Because `x` is used somewhere beside the constructor, Scala automatically creates private field for it as well. However no getters/setters are generated, it is accessed directly in `twisted` method (same as `d`).

UPDATE: In comments you are asking about renaming getters/setters. Here is even more complex example. Getters/setters are computing the value based on two fields at the same time:

```
class Foo {

    private[this] var first: Char = _
    private[this] var rest: String = _

    def fake = first + rest

    def fake_=(s: String) {
        first = s.head
        rest = s.tail
    }

}
```

Looks complicated inside, but from the outside it looks like good old property:

```
val foo = new Foo()
foo.fake = "ABC"
println(foo.fake)
```

Just like if it was:

```
class Foo(var fake: String)
```

Comment: And you wrote it all in 8 minutes? Its great! :D

Comment: Whats the code when you want `aProperty` but it is based on an attribute `aString : String`?

Comment: @aitchnyu: I keep editing ;-). Also I work a lot with Scala-Java integration.

Comment: Re. 1: The convention for getters is to have no parameter lists at all, not an empty parameter list.

Comment: Re 5: The main effect of `private[this]` is that `d` is not accessible even from other objects of the same class. You cannot even in `Foo` say `def bar(foo: Foo) = foo.d`

Comment: @MichałPolitowski: you are right, thanks, I corrected point 1.

Comment: If I want to create a POJO with a lot of public properties (50+ for example), is it okay if I create the class with no argument constructor and the properties are in body of class: `var a: Int = _, var b: Int = _, ...` ? Because if I put the properties (`a, b, ...`) as constructor argument (`class Foo(var a: Int, var b: Int,...`), the instantiation code (`new Foo(...)`) will be very long. I have asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787505/how-to-create-pojo-class-with-only-empty-constructor-in-scala) before, but I wonder if there is another solution.