# How to create POJO class with only empty constructor in Scala?

Tags: scala, pojo

I want to create POJO class in Scala with only default empty constructor. In java, it's like this:

```
public class Foo {
    private String name;

    private String address;

    ...

    //and the public getter/setter below...
}
```

In scala, I have seen that you can create POJO like this:

```
case class Foo(var name: String, var address: String, ...)
```

But in my case, the class will have many properties (around 50+), and I don't think instantiating the class with 50 constructor parameters is fit for this case.

**UPDATE:**

Also, the class's properties value can be set (it's not read-only). This is how I expect the usasge of the POJO class:

```
val foo = new Foo()
foo.name = "scala johnson"
foo.address = "in my sweeet dream, oh yeah"
...
```

Comment: This is not in the spirit of much scala code that is out there, but you could do something like `class Foo { private var bar: String = null }`

Comment: @BenReich: sorry for not being clear in my question. The class's properties value can be set outside the class definition, so I can't set the property as `private`.

Comment: POJO stands for "Plain Old Java Object", so shouldn't it be POSO?

Comment: @jhegedus has the answer, but it's worth emphasising that this is very much not scala style; `case class`es encourage you to fully initialise your objects on construction, so they can never be in an invalid state, which makes errors less likely (and using `.copy` rather than modifying encourages you to get your data flow right). By all means take your time, but do try to pick up the scala way of doing things - there's no point learning a language that doesn't change the way you think, after all.

Comment: @Imm: I don't know if it's justified to use `case class` if there are 50 properties, that means 50 constructor parameters. That will be the longest class insantiating code line that I ever face in my life.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to do this way? by storing the values in Map first, then pass the Map to the `case class`'s constructor, then the Map values are copied into the class' `val` properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about :

```
class C {
  var p1:String = _
  var p2:Int = _
}
```

Comment: What does underscore mean?

Comment: default value assignment , see SLS for more details here: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#variable-declarations-and-definitions

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to instantiate the class with parametrized constructor, and you are going to have many properties, then perhaps you need either an object (a collection of static properties and methods) or a non-case class.

Example of an object:

```
object Foo {
  val someString = "one"

  val someNumber = 42.5    
}
```

There can be also a non-case class. You can have a class without arguments though I am not sure why would you want to have a class in that case:

```
class Foo {
  val someString = "one"
  val someNumber = 42.5
}
```

You call them like that:

```
val myObjectString = Foo.someString

val myClass = new Foo
val myClassNumber = myClass.someNumber
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in my question. The class's properties value can be set, so I can't use `val`.

Comment: @suud then replace `val` with `var` (Although I wouldn't recommend that - probably your model needs revision if a mutable transport object aka 'bean' is required)

Comment: Yep, in general one should try to avoid using `var`s where possible, so if you need `var` may be you should consider redesigning your class. But you can use `var` as a class or object member, it's not forbidden.